# Indexing in Multidimensional ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I am new to ArrayList, i am kind of stuck here. can anyone please help.

```
ArrayList Arr = new ArrayList();
Arr = [['3454' , '546',[5,6,8,9]],['abc',7,'efg']]
```

I have input the values in an Arraylist and I want to know the size of an arraylist [5,6,8,9] which is inside the 0th element of main arraylist.
I tried Arr.get(0).get(2).size();
But this shows error in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: You have to cast `Arr.get(0)` to `ArrayList` to be able to call its methods.

Comment: It is showing in quickfix to add cast Arr.get(0)

Comment: What is the [mcve]? That code will not work and you are using raw types which is a bad idea. What is the actual error?

Comment: what changes i need to make in my code statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

```
@Test
    public void testSomething() {
        List<Object> innerList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> innerList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        innerList1.add("3454");
        innerList1.add("546");
        innerList1.add(Arrays.asList(new int[]{5, 6, 8, 9}));

        innerList2.add("abc");
        innerList2.add(7);
        innerList2.add("efg");


        List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(innerList1);
        list.add(innerList2);

        System.out.println(list.get(0).get(0));
        System.out.println(list.get(0).get(1));
        System.out.println(list.get(0).get(2));
        System.out.println(list.get(1).get(0));
        System.out.println(list.get(1).get(1));
        System.out.println(list.get(1).get(2));
    }
```

That's how you can do it.

Long answer:

You shouldn't do it that way, because you'll need to check each time for the type that you have there. It's ok to print these values but you won't be able to sum it up.

It feels for me that you just started with Java after spending some time with js and that's why you ask a question like that.

So my advice for you would be to start some course from basics of java.

Answer (score 0):

To breakdown the question:

1. To input the values you can create the nested ArrayLists in several different ways. For something short, you can use this approach.

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(
               Arrays.asList(new Object[]{
                       "3454",
                       "546",
                       new ArrayList(
                               Arrays.asList(5, 6, 8, 9)),
                       new ArrayList(
                               Arrays.asList(new Object[]{
                                       "abc", 7, "efg"
                               }))
               }));
```

2. To get the size of the [5,6,8,9] element you can do it this way. You need to do the cast to ArrayList as you mix different types in the main list.

```
arr.get(2) -> this will return ArrayList(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 8, 9))
(ArrayList) arr.get(2) -> this will cast it to ArrayList so you can call methods from ArrayList on it
```

Whole thing together:

```
int size = ((ArrayList) arr.get(2)).size();

System.out.println("Size: " + size);

>>>Size: 4
```